# javascript getElementsByClassName and setAttribute not working

Tags: javascript, styles, getelementsbyclassname

I've added 4 "range" type inputs, and use their values to set the RGBA value of another element, but it's not working.

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
document.getElementById("colorR").onchange() = setColors;
document.getElementById("colorG").onchange() = setColors;
document.getElementById("colorB").onchange() = setColors;
document.getElementById("Opacity").onchange() = setColors;  
}
function setColors(){
var r = document.getElementById("colorR").value;
var g = document.getElementById("colorG").value;
var b = document.getElementById("colorB").value;
var a = document.getElementById("Opacity").value;

    //alert(r+", "+g+", "+b+", "+a);

document.getElementsByClassName("previewAreaBox")[0].style.setAttribute(
"background-color", "rgba(",r+", "+g+", "+b+", "+a/100+");");

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Open your browser's developer console, and you'll see errors. That should be the first place you look when something isn't working.

Comment: When you are calling `document.getElementById("...").onchange() = setColors`, you are executing any attached function. take away the parenthesis so it looks like this: `document.getElementById("...").onchange = setColors`. That way you are setting the variable and the new value (a function) will be called later.

Comment: Thank you both Crazy Train and smakateer

Comment: mtd +1 to you because you are showing your appreciation when the majority of new users will take an answer and disappear. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Tnx for your kindness dear joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there are a few problems here

**1. You need to assign the function to the change event, not call the change event.**

**2. You don't use setAttribute on the style, you use that to set a attribute on a element.**

**3. You should be caching your elements.**

```
window.onload = init;


var elementR, elementG, elementB, opacityElement;

function init(){
   elementR = document.getElementById("colorR");
   elementG = document.getElementById("colorG");
   elementB = document.getElementById("colorB");
   opacityElement = document.getElementById("Opacity");

   // Set change events
   elementR.onchange = 
   elementG.onchange = 
   elementB.onchange = 
   opacityElement.onchange = setColors;
}
function setColors(){
    var r = elementR.value,
        g = elementG.value,
        b = elementB.value,
        a = opacityElement.value,
        preview = document.getElementsByClassName("previewAreaBox")[0];
        preview.style.backgroundColor =  'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a / 100 + ')';
}
```

---

```
Element.onchange() = something;
```

Won't work because `onchange();` actually triggers the event and doesn't assign the function to it.

You can also use `Array.join` for the rgba like so

```
var rgba = [elementR.value, elementG.value, elementB.value, 
            opacityElement.value / 100];
preview.style.backgroundColor =  'rgba(' + rgba.join(',') + ')';
```

Comment: Agreed, who is going along and down voting our answers?? Maybe it's our discussion style of answering. Some believe answerers should simply tell the answer and be done. That's what someone told me one time. (They repeated my same answer after me without my discussion, then got six times as many votes, and credit for having the correct answer. But the lesson I gained is that they told me why it probably happened. However, I still believe in explaining.)

Comment: Aww, i was looking forward to getting a badge for a accepted answer with minus votes.... but i didn't.....

Comment: I'm agree with you, explaining in more depth can serve more people from beginner to advanced ones

Comment: Actually, you already have the tenacious badge! Since it won't affect whether you get a badge, I'm going to +1 your answer because it's not fair for you to have -1 on it.

Answer (score 3):

```
style.setAttribute(
```

`setAttribute` applies to an element, not the style.

And `background-color` is a style-property, not an attribute.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("previewAreaBox")[0].style.backgroundColor = ".."
```

Answer (score 3):

At minimum,

```
document.getElementById("colorR").onchange() = setColors;
```

should be changed to

```
document.getElementById("colorR").onchange = setColors;
```

The rest of your code won't run at all without making that change, because `onchange()` invokes the event handler while `onchange` without parentheses is used to assign the event handler.

**ALSO**

As noted by Connor's helpful comment, Andy's answer contains part of the solution, and I also noticed one more error in your code:

```
"rgba(",r+", "+g+", "+b+", "+a/100+");"
```

needs to be something like this (plus where a comma is now, and parentheses around the arithmetic to keep its left operand from being converted to a string prematurely):

```
"rgba(" +r+ ", " +g+ ", " +b+ ", " + (a/100) +");"
```

So plugging that into Andy's answer, the `setColors` function should have its last line like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("previewAreaBox")[0].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(" +r+ ", " +g+ ", " +b+ ", " + (a/100) +");";
```